# How do I use rsync to put all new files into a separate directory?

Tags: rsync

I have two directories, A and B. I created B initially by just copying over everything from A. In the interim, other people have added files to B. I want to use rsync to pull all new files in B (i.e., files in B that aren't in A) into a new subdirectory C inside A. In addition, if I add new files to A I want them to show in B.

I had thought I could use `--compare-dest` or `--copy-dest` options but it seems they don't quite do what I'm looking for.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: How about files that were modified since they were copied?